# Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, base-link, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

says "map --> odom --> base_link"

and "Although intuition would say that both map and odom should be attached to base_link, this is not allowed because each frame can only have one parent."

In tf src,I have built two connections

```
    tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0,0,0, 1), tf::Vector3(0, 0, 0)),
    ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "base_laser")

    tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0,0,0, 1), tf::Vector3(20, 0, 0)),
    ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "odom")
```

If I write map->odom,it will says contain a loop.I don't know why.

```
    tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0,0,0, 1), tf::Vector3(0, 0, 0)),
    ros::Time::now(),"odom", "map")
```

My robot.launch says

```
  [ WARN] [1311950065.207360272]: Waiting on transform from /base_link to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Could not find a connection between '/map' and '/base_link' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.
```

1. What happened to base_link with two parents?
2. Why map->odom will contain a loop?
3. How to fix all the problems?
   Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10766/waiting-on-transform-from-/base_link-to-/map?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-29**:
The output of `rosrun tf view_frames` can be very helpful for debugging this type of problem. I suggest you run it while everything is running and attach the PDF here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are broadcasting those code-sniplets (for testing!), right?

You have to build a tree, or in this case a line as:
map -> odom -> base_link -> base_laser

If you look at the code sniplets you have posted, you can see, that you interchanged parent and child a bid.

You also have to continuously publish all transforms and later on obviously with real data.
If that doesn't help follow the comment by Eric Perko.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-30**:
Yeah,it's only for testing. And I am not really understand that what's the difference between "map->odom" and "odom->map"?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The difference between "map->odom" and "odom->map" is who is the parent and who the child in the tf tree.

In the example code that you posted you're publishing base_link as parent of base_laser and odom, and then map as parent of odom. Map and base_link cannot both be parents of odom.
The error that you reported usually happens when two parents of the same node are being published, resulting is an unconnected tree. I suggest you to visualize your tf tree using "rosrun tf view_frames" as Eric says.

It could be helpful to know which nodes are you running, because other nodes could be broadcasting tf transforms.

---

Originally posted by [luca](https://answers.ros.org/users/564/luca/) with karma: 96 on 2011-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-08-01**:
For such a degenerated tree it should work, but breaks the conventions. As soon as you have a robot with more than one sensor it will not work so easily anymore because you need a proper tree then where /map or some other fixed frame is the root.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-08-01**:
Yes,what I think is if "map -> odom -> base_link -> base_laser" is correct,can I change it to "base_laser -> base_link -> odom -> map" by the inversion you said and get the totally same result?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-07-31**:
No, since TF is not only about vectors but also about rotations. It's essentially the inverse transformation. The tree on a robot is defined by the links on the robot and you cannot interchange child and parent nodes randomly. Did you have a look at the tf tutorial videos on ros.org/wiki/tf?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-31**:
Sorry for the unclear question before. My question is if my program only have one transform between map and odom, the difference between "map->odom" and "odom->map" is the only value difference of positive sign or negative sign,right?